# Nested Query in spring batch processing

Tags: spring-batch

I want to create an ETL process using Spring Batch, the steps will be read from a DB(s) and insert in one DB so basically I'm collecting similar information from different DB and inserting them in one DB, I have a large complex query that I need to run on those DBs and the result will be inserted in the so called one DB for later processing, my main concert is that I want to reference this query in the JpaPagingItemReader for example, it there a way I can for example add this query in my project as .sql file and then reference it in the reader?

Or any other solution I can follow?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it there a way I can for example add this query in my project as .sql file and then reference it in the reader? Or any other solution I can follow?

You can put your query in a properties file and inject in your reader, something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MyJob {

    @Bean
    public JpaPagingItemReader itemReader(@Value("${query}") String query) {
        return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<>()
                .queryString(query)
                // set other reader properties
                .build();
    }

    // ...
}
```

In this example, you should have a property `query=your sql query` in `application.properties`. This is actually the regular Spring property injection mechanism, nothing Spring Batch specific here.

Comment: Awesome I will try that approach @Mahmoud Ben Hassine